# Deciphering of difficult Kurrent (?) handwriting

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

As you will see from my profile, I am interested in philosophy. Further to this, I am striving with transcribing and translating a lot of  philosophy related letters written in the German language during the 19th century, mainly with Kurrent handwriting. As I am neither trained in Kurrent handwriting, nor in the German grammar, I have problems both with interpreting words and do also often misinterpret the last letters in a word.

As you will see below, I have tried - at many places in vain - to transcribe the below and attached letter. **Any transcription help would be greatly appreciated**:

[Prof. Dr. Vaihinger – Redaction der ”Kantstudien“ – Halle a. S.
an Monrad]

[Page 1] Below numbers refer to the line number.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqzE4.jpg)

1   30.XI.96

2   Hochgeehrender Herr Kollege!

3   Es war mir im Drang der

4   amtlicher und redactionellen

5   Gestätte positiv unmöglich, Ihr

6   freundl. Schrieben von 30.X. früher

6   als heute zu beantworten, herein

7   Ihnen für Ihre liebenswürdige Mit-

8   theilung von 21. Nov. betr. die

9   Stelle aus Publikus Syrus früher

10  zu danken.  Letztere Notiz werde

11  ich im nächste Hefte bxxx das

12  so eben im Drücke ist.  Was Ihren

13  Aufsatz betrifft, xx ist allerdings

14  richtig dass ich in meinem ersten Brief

15  von den Überfälle des Arbeiten nicht

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUOpn.jpg)

16  gesprochen hatte: ich xxx den

17  Brief in ihr Reife auch xxx aus

18  der Sorglosigkeit der Reisenden

19  muss an die groze Aufsatz der

20  xxx in Aussicht stehenden Beiträge

21  dachte.  Ich bemerkte auch xxx

22  nachdem ich eine Überschlag machte

23  zu xxx mit Schritten wie mit

24  ich in nächste Zeit unterbringen

25  müsste.  Auch mit dem jetzt in

26  druck befindlicher Heft habe ich

27  wegen Überfülle „meine liebe

28  Noth“.  Auch das Redigiren ist

29  eine Kunst, wie der Regierog

30  und will erst sehr allmälig

31  gelernt sein.  Ich aber bin darin

32  uns in dem ersten Stadium ihr

33  Zennend.

34  Was nun Ihnen Aufsatz selbst

35  betriff so ist die Form derselben

[3]
36  xxx originär als mir wenig-

37  stens nicht erinnerlig ist, wenigstens in

38  den letzten Jahren einer ähnlichen

39  Versuch zuletzter zu sehen, in welchem

40  xxx dem xxx xxx ein

41  Denken um sich gemacht worden wäre,

42  aber dem Inhalt noch ist das, was

43  Sie sagen Gemeingut der deutschen

44  Idealismus den Sie ja ein xxx

45  energischer und origineller Weise

46  in Norwegen vertreten; speciell haben

47  alle Hegelianer der Sache nach den-

48  selben Standpunkt vertreten, und aus

49  dem Kantischen Ding an sich das

50  seine Denken gemacht.  Dass dieser

51  Standpunkt jetzt nicht merken ist, sagen

52  Sie selbst an Schluss Ihrer Aufsatzen

53  gar freilich kein sagengrund gegen den

54  Infall derselben ist: auch Kant war

55  lange Zeit nicht mehr moderne und ist das

56  wieder oben auf gekommen. Die Welt

57  xxx sich, warum sollte nicht auch Hegelsche

58  Philosophie wieder einmal modern werden?

[4]

59  Ich kann aber nur wiederholen

60  leider mir nicht möglich zzz AugenXXX

61  meiner XXX sonstigen Menschlichtungen

62  die ich früher angegangen habe Ihren

63  Aufsatz in Bälde zum Abdruck zu

64  bringen.  Auch würde ich, wie Ihre be-

65  merkt, den Schluss ihr Aufsatzes erg-

66  lassen müssen von ihr xxx in meinem

67  letzte Briefe bezeichneten Stelle an.  Ich

68  kann nicht an Ihnen verlangen bei Ihrem

69  hohen Alter, was ich sonst verlangen

70  müsste, beliebige Zeit zu warten, bis

71  die Reihe an Ihren Aufsatz kommt.  Das-

72  selb muss ich mich darauf bexxx

73  der Frühre zu weitholen, resp auf

74  der XXX Gesagte zu wenigsten

75  und zeichne mit aufsichtiger Hochachtung

76  Ihr ganz ergebnester

77  Waihinger

The letter was written in 1896 by Hans Vainiger https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Vaihinger to Marcus Jacob Monrad https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Jacob_Monrad (for a far more correct description of Monrad's Hegelian position, I do recommend Meyers Konversationslexikon, 6. Auflage 1906 - "Sein philosophischer Standpunkt ist ein gemäßigt Hegelscher").

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say that, but I think, you should not put so much energy into translating (especially philosophical) texts from or into a language that you are not really good in. How do you want to decipher a handwritten letter, if you have no idea, what it could mean? For such a project - and be sure that I admire your drive to do so - you need someone who is an expert in the source language. I think, this side can not take the place of sb. like that. Anyway: good luck and +1 for such an interesting question (and project).

Comment: In addition to what @Olafant said: the resolution of your posted scans is much too low to be helpful, even to native speakers of German.

Comment: I have now added better pictures.

Comment: Are you aware of http://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de/gerd.simon/fiktionalismus1.htm and in particular https://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de/gerd.simon/chrvai.pdf? It quotes the library in Bremen as source for that letter. Maybe they have a transcription or digital version. Or is that what you show here like the red sigil at the top suggests?

Comment: The question was closed because "it needs details or clarity". I cannot see which details are missing or what is unclear.

Comment: Imho it should be closed, but for bulk proofreading/translation request, not for missing details.

Answer (score 6):

Below, please find a completed transcription made by
Sütterlinstube Hamburg e.V.

Prof. Dr. Vaihinger  – Redaction der ”Kantstudien “ – Halle a. S.
[an Monrad ]

30.XI.96.
Hochzuverehrender Herr Kollege!

Es war mir im Drang der
amtlichen und redactionellen
Geschäfte positiv unmöglich, Ihr
freundl. Schreiben vom 30.X. früher
als heute zu beantworten, sowie
Ihnen für Ihre liebenswürdige Mit-
theilung vom 21. Nov., betr. die
Stelle aus Publilius  Syrus früher
zu danken. Letztere Notiz werde
ich im nächsten Hefte bringen, das
so eben im Drucke ist. Was Ihren
Aufsatz betrifft, so ist allerdings
richtig, daß ich in meinem ersten Briefe
von der Überfülle der Arbeiten nicht
gesprochen hatte: ich schrieb den
Brief von der Reise aus wo ich mit
der Sorglosigkeit der Reisenden
nicht an die große Anzahl der
schon in Aussicht stehenden Beiträge
dachte. Ich bemerkte erst nachher,
nachdem ich einen Überschlag machte
zu Haus & mit Schrecken, wie viel
ich in nächster Zeit unterbringen
müßte. Auch mit dem jetzt im
Druck befindlichen Heft habe ich
wegen Überfülle „meine liebe
Noth“. Auch das Redigiren ist
eine Kunst, wie das Regieren
und will erst sehr allmälig
gelernt sein. Ich aber bin darin
noch in dem ersten Stadium des
Lernens.
Was nun Ihnen Aufsatz selbst
betrifft, so ist die Form deßelben
insofern originär, als mir wenig-
stens nicht erinnerlich ist, wenigstens in
den letzten Jahren einen ähnlichen
Versuch gelesen zu haben, in welchem
aus dem Kantischen Noumenon  ein
Denken an sich gemacht worden wäre,
aber dem Inhalt nach ist das, was
Sie sagen, Gemeingut des deutschen
Idealismus, den Sie ja in so
energischer und origineller Weise
in Norwegen vertreten; speciell haben
alle Hegelianer der Sache nach den-
selben Standpunkt vertreten, und aus
dem Kantischen Ding an sich das
reine Denken gemacht. Daß dieser
Standpunkt jetzt nicht modern ist, sagen
Sie selbst an Schluß Ihres Aufsatzes
was freilich kein Gegengrund gegen den
Inhalt deßelben ist: auch Kant war
lange Zeit nicht mehr modern, und ist doch
wieder oben auf gekommen. Die Welt
dreht sich, warum sollte nicht auch Hegelsche
Philosophie wieder einmal modern werden?
Ich kann aber nur wiederholen,
daß es mir nicht möglich würde, angesichts
meiner vielen sonstigen Verpflichtungen,
die ich früher eingegangen habe, Ihren
Aufsatz in Bälde zum Abdruck zu
bringen. Auch würde ich, wie schon be-
merkt, den Schluß des Aufsatzes weg-
lassen müßen, von der schon in meinem
letzten Briefe bezeichneten Stelle an. Ich
kann nicht von Ihnen verlangen bei Ihrem
hohen Alter, was ich sonst verlangen
müßte, beliebige Zeit zu warten, bis
die Reihe an Ihren Aufsatz kommt. Deß-
halb muß ich mich darauf beschränken,
das frühere zu wiederholen, resp auf
das früher Gesagte zu verweisen,
und zeichne mit aufrichtiger Hochachtung
Ihr
ganz ergebenster
H. Vaihinger.